# Why is WinHttpHandler causing "Unable to load DLL 'api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-0.dll'" on production server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dll

We've started using the [WinHttpHandler](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler/) NuGet package in an ASP.NET application. On the development machines it's working fine, and also works on our staging environment. The application targets .NET 4.6.1.

However, on production it throws the following error:

```
System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-0.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
```

I have googled quite a lot about this problem, but couldn't find any meaningful information about this dll. (I found in forums that some people manually copied the dlls to their production servers when having similar issues, but that doesn't seem to be the proper solution.)

Where is this dll coming from? Should it be explicitly installed?

(On my dev machine I found it in `C:\Windows\System32`, on our staging machine it's in `C:\Windows\System32\downlevel`, but I don't know where it's coming from.)

Comment: What is the server operating system version?

Comment: It's Windows Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have a problem with [API Sets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh802935(v=vs.85).aspx).
That dll is only available for [Windows 8 API Sets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn505783(v=vs.85).aspx), and as it is stated on msdn

> API Sets rely on operating system support in the library loader to
>   effectively introduce a namespace redirection component into the
>   library binding process. Subject to various inputs, including the API
>   Set name and the binding (import) context, the library loader performs
>   a runtime redirection of the reference to a target host binary that
>   houses the appropriate implementation of the API Set.

So my suggestion is to contact the owner of the package and describe in detail the environment in which you are using that package (operating system, Target .Net Framework Identifier, Target .Net Framework Version, etc).
Hopefully they will find and fix the error.

**UPDATE:** Here is a discussion on [GitHub page](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/8091) of the package. The proper long-term solution for this problem is not clear yet.

TLDR: Installing [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015](https://chocolatey.org/packages/vcredist2015) solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I'll contact the package maintainer (Microsoft :)), and update the thread if I find out something.